# Growl-type messages in Ubuntu

Tags: python, development, dbus, libnotify

I'm working on a Python application that runs in the system tray and displays notifications to the user in the form of popups. It uses Growl on Macs and Growl for Windows on Windows. I've tried notify-send in Ubuntu, but it won't display a new message until the last message displayed goes away. Sometimes, I need to display 2 messages in quick succession, so that's no good. What else is out there that I could use?

Comment: Please check the wiki documentation on [Notify OSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD). There are a few parameters that can be adjusted. The [notification development guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines) is also definitely worth a read for notify-osd customization and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using the external `notify-send`, I suggest you use the `pynotify` library, and then [you can append to existing notifications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines#How_to_use_the_append-hint) and the bubble will grow.

Comment: That looks like what I want, but I can't find any documentation. Any idea where I could dig some up?

Comment: The docs seem pretty thin: I suggest you just read the source, and ask questions on here or irc or stack overflow.